# Getting values of elements in same row when button is clicked, one button per row

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, razor

I have a table, each row of which contains a button and some elements.
I want to get the value of some of those elements when the button is clicked, and then pass it through to an Ajax call.

My problem is getting the value of those elements.

A table row looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="item_AllocationId" name="item.AllocationId" type="hidden" value="39">
        <input class="form-control input-width-medium text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Description field is required." id="item_Description" name="item.Description" type="text" value="Welcome Centre Rent">
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="checker" id="uniform-item_GiftAidable"><span><input class="uniform checkbox" id="item_GiftAidable" name="item.GiftAidable" type="checkbox" value="true"></span></div><input name="item.GiftAidable" type="hidden" value="false">
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="checker" id="uniform-isActive"><span class="checked"><input checked="checked" class="uniform checkbox" id="isActive" name="item.IsActive" type="checkbox" value="true"></span></div><input name="item.IsActive" type="hidden" value="false">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="update-allocation" type="submit" name="update-allocation" value="Update">
    </td>

</tr>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.update-allocation').click(function (event) {
        var isactive = $(this).parent().find('#isActive:checkbox:checked');
        alert(isactive);
    });
});
```

Which at least finds an object, but as soon as I but .val() in there it comes up undefined.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coastcoder/owoze110/)

Am I heading in the right direction? Or have I got completely lost in the DOM?

FYI the HTML is generated using ASP.Net Razor.

Comment: Are you trying to get the value of the description text field?

Comment: Yes, but I know I've done that somewhere before so I reckon (hope!) I can manage that bit :). In my rummaging around in the jQuery docs I found that ':checkbox:checked' was needed, but was still not getting the value, hence the question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a fiddle with an example
https://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/owoze110/5/

What I did is cache the parent row `<tr>`, and then used that as a reference. From there you can find the value of the specific field(s). I did it for description in this example:

```
$('.update-allocation').click(function (event) {
    var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
    var desc = $row.find('input[name="item.Description"]').val();
    var gift = $row.find('input[name="item.GiftAidable"]').is(':checked');
    var isActive = $row.find('input[name="item.IsActive"]').is(':checked');

    alert('description: ' + desc + '\ngift aidable: ' + gift + '\nis active: '+isActive);
});
```

Also, I noticed that you're using the same ID attribute for all your input. I would recommend you use class instead, since you should only have one instance of an ID. Let me know if you have additional questions. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Gene, much appreciated. I'll give this a whirl as well later, off to get some much needed food :)

Comment: @CoastCoder I updated the fiddle, try this https://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/owoze110/5/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery *always** returns an object. In this case, the object it's returning is empty, which you cannot tell from a simple `alert(isactive)` (although you could do `alert(isactive.length)`).

The problem lies in the following code:

```
$(this).parent().find('#isActive:checkbox:checked')
```

The parent of `.update-allocation` is its `td` element, which doesn't contain `#isActive`.

I would suggest using [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the closest parent `tr`:

```
$(this).closest("tr").find('#isActive:checkbox:checked')
```

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/owoze110/1/

<sub><sub>*Unless you call a function like .is which doesn't.</sub></sub>

Comment: Thanks! Did the trick. Just a couple of points though, for checkboxes which are not ticked, the result is 'undefined'. Now as this is going to a ASP.Net app, I'm not sure how that will behave. I tried detecting the case and setting the value to false, but the check doesn't appear to work.
I've updated the jsfiddle to show what I'm trying. Also, apologies for replacing consol.log with alerts, but I couldn't see where that was being output to. Sorry, jQuery's not really my thing :(